# Mesh's Smooth Shade Problem

Tags: mesh

i used smooth shade in a mesh and it responde me with a
strange behavior. Some parts of my mesh has smooth shade but for other parts it doesn't have. I tried recalculate inside/outside normals. And a few other things i have read but none of them has worked so far. And one more importing thing is that when i try scultping mode it starts working but as i went back to object mode and render it doesn't work.

[image]

This is object mode. As you can see above some parts of it has smooth shade other parts doesn't.

[image]

And in this sculpt mode. Which works fine.

[image]

And last this one above is different mesh. The look i want in the first mesh should be like this. But can't find a way to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, i found out a solution. If someone has a problem like this, what it i did is; I joined smooth shade problem mesh to non smooth shade mesh(This mesh has smooth shade working). And as i joined it fixed ! Then i separate the mesh i joined. That's all i hope this might help someone.